# To block outgoing connections from redhat 7 using firewall-cmd

Tags: networking, iptables, firewalld

Is there a way to block all outgoing connections from redhat 7 using `firewall-cmd` or `iptables` except for one IP.
It will make connections to specific IP while drop all connections to the rest.

I know this command to drop all connections but couldn't figure out how to allow external connections to only one IP

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth1 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

`iptables` rules are generally evaluated until first matching rule. If you only want to allow traffic based on source/destination IP address, create rules to allow such traffic, and change the default action to reject/drop the rest. With such configuration, you also should add rules to allow loopback traffic.

For output chain:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d <ip-address> -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUPUT REJECT
```

Similar rules for input chain:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s <ip-address> -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```